# How to add elements dynamically if they are stored in database

Tags: java, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are design patterns to support custom fields in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126783/what-are-design-patterns-to-support-custom-fields-in-an-application)

I use SQLite to store my data. I have several columns in the table like `id`, `title`, `description` and `notes`. Now I need to extend my data model and keep `other 1`, `other 2`, ... , `other N` fields in database. I want the user to add them dynamically.

I just don't know how to handle the case because the amount of columns in the table is fixed. What's approach for this case?

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to use Attribute-Value-Pair pattern where you can have separate table with following schema:

- id (from your original table)
- attributeName (that can be your other 1, other 2, etc).
- attributeValue

You can further normalize this approach, by creating separate table for your attributes, for example with following schema:

- Id
- Name
- DataType

Then your original table would become

- id
- attributeId
- attributeValue

Comment: EAV is only appropriate when you have a large number of possible values, but a small number of actual values (patient symptoms in a doctor's office, for example), and there are significant disadvantages to this approach.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model for more information.

Comment: I agree with @Sebastian approach but in the last more normalized case the original entity disappear you don't have any more a list of things, now you have a list of attributes, I know is a little more complicated but I prefer maintain the original entity table, add an second table Extended_Properties_List and a relational table that cross Entity_id, Property_id and value.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` syntax.  More info [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php).

SQLite doesn't support all [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) features.  See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) for those features in the SQL92 specification that are not supported.

Comment: This would result in empty columns for some rows which don't have additional fields.

Comment: You can't specify columns on a per-row basis.  If you want per-row attached values, look into [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).